# Understanding GPS GNSS RINEX FILES and relevant parameters

Tags: gps

I have a series of questions regarding RINEX files and its derivables:

For a typical RINEX file

(refer to: http://gage14.upc.es/gLAB/HTML/Observation_Rinex_v2.10.html) :

1) What does `APPROX POSITION XYZ refer to? Is it the position of the receiver antenna or the satellite?

2) If I would like derive a plot of 'signal noise' over time, what should be the parameters/values to look out for?

3) How is ellipsoidal height derived from a RINEX file?

4) For a raw RINEX file such as the above, is any correction of any form necessary?

5) I noticed that the data frequency is 30 seconds in the RINEX file above. What do the changing values within each interval refer/correspond to?

6) Is there any RINEX viewing/processing application? I believe MATLAB allows viewing of RINEX files.

Comment: anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

1. According to the RINEX 2.11 [specification](http://igscb.jpl.nasa.gov/igscb/data/format/rinex211.txt) provided by NASA, 'APPROX POSITION XYZ' refers to the position of the marker. The coordinates are defined by WGS84. The 'ANTENNA: DELTA H/E/N' header line tells you the offset of the antenna relative to the marker. These coordinates are typically extracted from the raw data file downloaded from the receiver when the RINEX file is created. However, these coordinates can be modified by the user at the time of creation. Typically the position is of psuedorange quality (don't rely on it for precise applications).
2. The '# / TYPES OF OBSERV' header line defines the order and type of observables that are present in the observation file. You are probably looking for S1 (signal-to-noise for L1) and S2 (signal-to-noise for L2). If more than 5 types are present for a given epoch and satellite, then they will be continued on the next line. This makes writing a RINEX parser somewhat difficult. You may want to consider using a software library like [GPSTk](http://www.gpstk.org/bin/view/Documentation/WebHome) to help with parsing the RINEX and dumping the observable that you are interested in. Check out the GPSTk RinDump utility. If S1 or S2 are not present in the file, then you are out of luck if you don't have access to the raw data file.
3. Excluding the approximate position in the header, RINEX files do not contain position estimates. RINEX simply provides the raw observables from each satellite that are used to compute positions. Ellipsoid height is not relevant until you convert an XYZ position into Lat/Lon/Height. If all you care about is the Approx. position, then you simply need to convert the approx. XYZ coordinates to LLH. There are many utilities available to do that. There are several free processing services available online that support RINEX. For an example check out [OPUS](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/OPUS/). Most support static processing, some support kinematic processing.
4. Well let's just say that when you process RINEX data to obtain position estimates, there are all sorts of error sources that must be accounted for a user to obtain accurate position estimates. If you're interested, check out books like [Global Positioning System: Signals, Measurments, and Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0970954425)  for more information.
5. Those are the observations for each epoch (time of the observation).
6. There are a few free tools out there. For example, [TEQC](https://www.unavco.org/software/data-processing/teqc/teqc.html) is a command line tool for translating, editing and quality checking RINEX data. You'll also find a few tools that can help you to visualize the RINEX data from the output of TEQC on their website. GPSTK also has utilities that help with that.